# Android Geocoder

Tags: java, android, android-studio

In my android application I do reverse Geocode (address from latitude and longitude) . My layout display 9 addresses from Geocoder, but sometimes from start activity to display adresses it takes 15 seconds. How to make it faster? Here is my one method (one of nine) to get one address:

```
  public void aktualizujRynek() {

  Thread thread1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
   public void run() {
    HttpURLConnection connection = null;
    try {
     URL myUrl = new URL("http://......http request....................");
     connection = (HttpURLConnection) myUrl.openConnection();
     InputStream iStream = connection.getInputStream();
     final String fResponse = IOUtils.toString(iStream);
     final TextView fView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.button8);
     fView.post(new Runnable() {
      @Override
      public void run() {
       // fView.setText("RESPONSE" + fResponse);
      }
     });
     final boolean post = fView.post(new Runnable() {

      @Override
      public void run() {

       //parse
       JSONObject root = null;
       try {
        root = new JSONObject(fResponse);
       } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
       }
       try {
        //Lat Lon
        String Lat = root.getString("Lat");
        double Lat_double = Double.parseDouble(Lat);
        String Lon = root.getString("Lon");
        double Lon_double = Double.parseDouble(Lon);

        //not current measurement
        String epoch_czujnik = root.getString("Epoch");
        long epoch_czujnik_long = Long.parseLong(epoch_czujnik); //czas ostatniego odczytu
        long epoch = System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000; //current time
        long roznica1 = epoch - epoch_czujnik_long;

        //lokalizacja ze współrzędnych
        Geocoder geocoder;
        List < Address > addresses;
        geocoder = new Geocoder(MainActivity.this, Locale.getDefault());
        addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(Lat_double, Lon_double, 1);
        String address = addresses.get(0).getAddressLine(0);
        String firstWords = address.substring(0, address.lastIndexOf(" "));
        String city = addresses.get(0).getLocality();

        //localization

        if (roznica1 > 7200) {
         String komunikat = "(czujnik nie działa)";
         if (city.equals(firstWords)) {
          final TextView fView102 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.button8);
          fView102.setText(city + System.getProperty("line.separator") + komunikat);
         } else {
          final TextView fView102 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.button8);
          fView102.setText(city + System.getProperty("line.separator") + firstWords + System.getProperty("line.separator") + komunikat);
         }

        } else {
         if (city.equals(firstWords)) {
          final TextView fView102 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.button8);
          fView102.setText(city);
         } else {
          final TextView fView102 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.button8);
          fView102.setText(city + System.getProperty("line.separator") + firstWords);

         }

        }

        //color
        String kolor = root.getString("Color");
        TextView test = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.button8);
        if (roznica1 > 7200) {
         test.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#b3b3b3"));
        } else {
         test.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor(kolor));

        }

        //IJP
        String ijp1 = root.getString("IJP");

       } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
       } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
       }
       //end parse
      }

     });

    } catch (MalformedURLException ex) {
     Log.e(TAG, "Invalid URL", ex);
    } catch (IOException ex) {
     Log.e(TAG, "IO / Connection Error", ex);

    } finally {
     if (connection != null)
      connection.disconnect();
    }
   }

  });
  thread1.start();

 }
```

Comment: It would be better to narrow down the code which spends the most time.
If the network request takes too much time, just a a progress bar to notify the user.

Comment: Thanks GeorgeChen.When data are loaded I have statement for user "loading data" , maybe I will make progress bar instead. With network request there is no problem, works fast, but when I add Geocoder, it made aplication slow working.